# How to remove formated mask to a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I want to remove formated mask(either '$' or 'S/.') to the value. I have two angular directives. those are [1st directive.](https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/70/) and [2nd directive.](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/xKrYp/)

In the second directive the symbol is not at all effecting to ng-model but the first directive it is effecting to ng-model.The first directive is removing the symbol, But if the text box is contains ng-change functions, it is calling ng-change functions then it is going to directive. so the symbol is effecting to ng-model.

The second directive is the symbol is not at all effecting to ng-model. Like this I need to the first directive too.

**Second directive:-**

```
app.directive('realTimeCurrency', function ($filter, $locale) {
    var decimalSep = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP;
    var toNumberRegex = new RegExp('[^0-9\\' + decimalSep + ']', 'g');
    var trailingZerosRegex = new RegExp('\\' + decimalSep + '0+$');
    var filterFunc = function (value) {
        return $filter('currency')(value);
    };

    function getCaretPosition(input){
        if (!input) return 0;
        if (input.selectionStart !== undefined) {
            return input.selectionStart;
        } else if (document.selection) {
            // Curse you IE
            input.focus();
            var selection = document.selection.createRange();
            selection.moveStart('character', input.value ? -input.value.length : 0);
            return selection.text.length;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    function setCaretPosition(input, pos){
        if (!input) return 0;
        if (input.offsetWidth === 0 || input.offsetHeight === 0) {
            return; // Input's hidden
        }
        if (input.setSelectionRange) {
            input.focus();
            input.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        }
        else if (input.createTextRange) {
            // Curse you IE
            var range = input.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', pos);
            range.moveStart('character', pos);
            range.select();
        }
    }

    function toNumber(currencyStr) {
        return parseFloat(currencyStr.replace(toNumberRegex, ''), 10);
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {    
            modelCtrl.$formatters.push(filterFunc);
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (newViewValue) {
                var oldModelValue = modelCtrl.$modelValue;
                var newModelValue = toNumber(newViewValue);
                modelCtrl.$viewValue = filterFunc(newModelValue);
                var pos = getCaretPosition(elem[0]);
                elem.val(modelCtrl.$viewValue);
                var newPos = pos + modelCtrl.$viewValue.length -
                                   newViewValue.length;
                if ((oldModelValue === undefined) || isNaN(oldModelValue)) {
                    newPos -= 3;
                }
                setCaretPosition(elem[0], newPos);
                return newModelValue;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**First directive:-**

```
app.directive('format', ['$filter', '$compile', function($filter, $compile) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        val: '=val'
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

        if (!ctrl) return;
        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(a) {

          if (attrs.symbol == '$')
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue, '$')
          else
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
        });

                scope.$watch(function() {
            return elem.val()
        }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
          var a = newVal;
          var plainNumber = a.split('.').filter(function(e) {
            return (e.length > 0);
          }).join('.');
          var i = 0;
          if (isNaN(parseFloat(plainNumber))) {
            i = (attrs.symbol == '$') ? 1 : 3;
          }
          var num = plainNumber.substring(i, plainNumber.length).replace(/,/g, '');
          if (attrs.symbol == '$')
            elem.val($filter('currency')(num, attrs.symbol));
          else
            elem.val($filter('currency')(num));
          var n = parseFloat(num);
          scope.val = Number(n);
          if (!scope.$$phase) {
            $compile(elem.contents())(scope)
          }
        });
      }
    };

    // controller 
  }])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, you want to remove `$` and/or `S\.` from a string which represents a number.

Hope this will work just fine:

```
plainNumber.replace(/(\S\/\.|\$)/g, '');
```

Comment: the first directive is removing the symbol. But if the text box contains any event's like ng-change then it is calling the ng-change then it is calling the directive. So it is effecting to ng-model in ng-change. If you observe the second directive. It is not at all effecting to ng-model even it contains ng-change

Comment: You need to either make the function a filter, or add a watch for your variable, and every time the value changes you have to rerun the `replace` function.

Comment: I am fresher to angular, can you give me example with plnknr